# Can't find python module [Anaconda]

Tags: python, anaconda

I've installed the new Anaconda 5.1. Before that, I had Anaconda 4 installed on my Windows 10 computer.

However I'm only able to use the preinstalled anaconda modules like `numpy`, `matplotlib`. If I install a new module for example over pip I can't use it, because my IDE (Visual Studio Code, pyCharm or Jupyter Notebook) will not find it. If I open the python console directly, I can import any module. The IDEs use the correct python path.

I've reinstalled anaconda a few times, but without any positive result.

Anyone with the same problem have a solution?

Comment: Using Anaconda 5.1 here on Win10, I can't reproduce this problem. I executed `pip install regex` from the Anaconda prompt and could then import it immediately from a running qtconsole or from VSCode. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question on 100%, but you can try this approach:

1) Open Anaconda prompt

2) Type `conda install [packagename]`

Comment: @BertBaker, any feedback? was my proposal useful?